# Update speed issues when left joining on date field

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, join

I have a table which stores time series data points in MySQL 5.6 called `data_points`

```
CREATE TABLE `data_points` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time_series_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `logged_at` date NOT NULL,
  `data_value` decimal(20,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upload_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `is_latest` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `data_points_time_series_id_index` (`time_series_id`),
  KEY `data_points_logged_at_index` (`logged_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The `is_latest` flag indicates if the data point is the latest for a given `logged_at` date and given `time_series_id`. When new data points are inserted I need to keep the old revisions but set their `is_latest` flag to `0`.

For example on `2018-01-01` I insert the first data point with a value of `1457.2` for `time_series_id` `123`. The default value of `is_latest` is `1`.

Later on I want to revise that data point value (whilst leaving the existing row in place for reasons of point in time analysis). So I insert a new data point for `2018-01-01` with a value of `44795.778` for `time_series_id` `123`.

I now need to set the `is_latest` flag to `0` for the old revision.

I have an update query to do this but it's taking ~400ms to execute with ~3 million rows in the `data_points` table...

```
UPDATE data_points o
LEFT JOIN data_points o2
  ON o2.time_series_id = o.time_series_id
  AND o2.logged_at = o.logged_at
SET o.is_latest = 0
WHERE o.is_latest = 1
  AND o.time_series_id = 123
  AND o.upload_id < o2.upload_id;
```

I think the issue is on the self join on `o2.logged_at = o.logged_at`, when joining on dates.

Is there any more efficient way to define which of the `data_points` rows should be marked as `is_latest = 0`?

Comment: 400 ms for an update on a table with 3 million rows is pretty reasonable.  Presumably, you already have an index on `data_points(time_series_id, logged_at)`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, yeah I have an index on time_series_id and logged_at. I'm doing this ~3500 times per batch import so the 400 ms adds up. If at all possible I'd like to remove the bottleneck.

Comment: . . Your problem is that you are doing multiple `update`s rather than a single `update`.

Comment: I have to do one update per batch as the data points are sharded over multiple DBs.

Comment: . . You should probably collect more than one id in a batch and do the updates in "batches" rather than as singletons.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your initial suggestion of using a composite index was what I was missing. Updates are now taking ~16 ms. If you post this as an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
UPDATE data_points o LEFT JOIN
       data_points o2
       ON o2.time_series_id = o.time_series_id AND
          o2.logged_at = o.logged_at
    SET o.is_latest = 0
WHERE o.is_latest = 1 AND
      o.time_series_id = 123 AND
      o.upload_id < o2.upload_id;
```

You want two indexes:  `data_points(is_latest, time_series_id)` and `data_points(time_series_id, logged_at, upload_id)`.  The first may already be covered by your existing indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(time_series_id, is_latest, o.upload_id)
```

But, I wonder.  Why have the `is_latest` flag, when "largest upload_id" has the same meaning?  Let's see the query that makes use of `is_latest` and see if we can get rid of the flag.  That would make the query 100% faster by getting rid of it!

Comment: Thanks Rick, the largest `upload_id` value does not necessarily mean that the data point is the latest.

Comment: Here is a query to get all of the latest data points for a time series:
    `SELECT *
    FROM data_points o
    WHERE o.`time_series_id` = 123
    AND o.`is_latest` = 1;`

Without the is_latest flag I have to self join on the `data_points` table like so:
    `SELECT *
    FROM data_points o
    LEFT JOIN data_points o2
    ON o.logged_at = o2.logged_at
    AND o.upload_id < o2.upload_id
    AND o.time_series_id = o2.time_series_id
    WHERE o.time_series_id = 123
    AND o.upload_id <= 4
    AND o2.upload_id IS NULL;`

Comment: The technique for groupbise max that involves `o.upload_id < o2.upload_id` performs very poorly, as I discuss [_here_](mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) .